# Should Magento clear "selectedShippingRate" when products are removed from cart?

Tags: checkout

After adding a "Click & Collect" product to the shopping cart, the variable for "selectedShippingRate" is stored in "Local Storage > mage-cache-storage > checkout-data" as "clickncollect_clickncollect_default", it remains there after removing the products from the cart, adding a "Delivery" product afterwards is still seen as "Click & Collect".

Should Magento be clearing this on it's own when a cart is emptied?